# How do you formally wish someone well?

Tags: translation, phrase-requests

A formal way to wish someone well in English is to say "may [good things happen to you]", filling in whatever specific blessing you intend to give. For instance, "May you always be happy."

I know that this might be done using the imperative, such as "Vi ĉiam gaju," but there's no explicit "wishing" here. It might be translated as a command: "You! Always be happy." Do I need to say "Mi esperas ke, vi ĉiam gajas," or is there a more succinct, formal method?

And what about when you want to wish yourself well?

Here's some examples of what I'd like to translate:

- May your days be merry and bright
- May he live forever
- May the stars guide me

Dankon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to express this could be with the word *deziri*. The Reta Vortaro has this as one of its definitions:

> Esprimi al iu bonvolan esperon, ke li ĝuu ian feliĉaĵon

If you search for “deziras al vi”, there are many examples of this in the [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com):

> Mi deziras al vi multajn jarojn de ekzistado
>
> Mi deziras al vi bonan tagon, sinjoro!
>
> Mi deziras al vi, ke vi finu la aferon en la plej agrabla maniero

Using the same formula, maybe you could translate your example phrases as follows:

> Mi deziras al vi ĝojajn kaj brilajn tagojn
>
> Mi deziras al li ke li vivu ĉiame

I think your last example seems a little different and is more like a prayer rather than a polite blessing. I would be more inclined to translate that with a simple imperative:

> La steloj gvidu min

Answer (score 4):

Neil's answer is fine. I would like to add that when using the Esperanto *-u* (*fartu* bone, *pasigu* gajan vesperon, *ĝuu* la vivon) you are not giving a command. It is not impolite or rude to tell somebody "*longe vivu kaj prosperu*" or "*fartu bone*". That's why it is not called *imperativo* in Esperanto but rather *volitivo* or simply *u-modo*.

The Plena Ilustrita Vortaro says: "*-u. verba finaĵo esprimanta deziron aŭ volon*" (an ending denoting dezire or wish). It can be used in commands, even impolitely (*foriru!, silentu!*), but it's not the *u* that makes them sound not so friendly.

Your examples might well be translated

- *Estu la tagoj al vi gajaj kaj brilaj*
- *Li vivu eterne*
- *La steloj gvidu min*

Even with the *-u* they would remain socially correct and suitable in formal contexts, too.